# Browser render issue in iframe inside SharePoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint, iframe, internet-explorer-8

I am trying to diagnose a problem with an internal production application.

We have SharePoint 2007 with a content editor page that hosts an iframe.

Inside this iframe is a simple aspx web page that displays a table of comments and lets you add more comments.

The comments are inside a textarea.

Parts of the comment gets duplicated on display.

I am testing with a comment "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ....  35 36 37 38 39 40"

[image: Static View of the Rendered textarea]

You can see the first line runs to 25 then wraps to the next line and starts back over at 19.

The actual HTML source is correct.

If I view the page directly, instead of from inside the iframe in sharepoint, it renders correctly.

If I create a test web page with an iframe showing this content, it renders correctly.

Firefox renders correctly both the SharePoint site and the test web page.

I have tried several search terms and google, but to no avail.

[image: Showing the Highlight Error]

I have only reproduced the error on Domain Computers (XP and 7) with IE 8. I have not tested with IE 9.

Using a basic install of XP and IE8 on a VPN to the corporate network renders correctly.

Any ideas on this problem and how to fix it?  Could it be a GPO Policy causing the problem?

------- UPDATE ----------

Using the Internet Explorer tools, I have determined that the page will render in IE 8 correctly.  It does not render correctly in IE7 or IE8 Compatibility Mode.

Internet Explorer 8 renders **intranet** pages in IE8 compatibility mode by default.

Comment: why not change iframe to div -- if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />` to the head of the page to force IE8 not to switch to compatibility mode for an intranet page.

This **does not** fix the issue for IE 7